# How to save HTML list number in JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a HTML page where I can create lists from a javascript. It saves the data in JSON. To the list there is also a javascript, which makes it possible to drag and sort the list items if you want to do so. *All the javascripts are independent of each other.*

My problem is that I don't know how I should index these list items in the order they have been placed, and afterwards send it to the database. Of course all this should happen on the client before sending it to database.

Remember this question is ONLY about storing the right index number in each list item; in the right order. If I would change the order of a list item, the index number should change too, so it will be saved in the right order.

Comment: need more information about implementation, but as long as you put the list in a JSON array, order will be preserved.

Comment: Uh what? If you change the order of items in an array, then those items have different indexes... automatically. I think you have to provide more information and an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the collection just before saving them and assign the current values.

I did this with a menu I built once. In jQuery I did something like this:

```
$("#mylist li").each(function(inx){
    $(this).attr('index',inx);
});
```

Then, when you save them, include the `index` attribute so you know the final order.

EDIT: per comment by @Boaz

Comment: Note `each` already passes the iterator's index to the function. You just have to assign it: `$("#mylist li").each(function(i) {console.log(i)});`. So there's no need for a global variable.